# Can't remove bluetooth iPhone 3GS from OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, bluetooth, iphone

I paired my 3GS for network tethering and it worked fine until I closed my MacBook.  Now it says that I'm connected to my phone when I am not.  Clicking the 'Disconnect from Network' button does nothing. And in the Bluetooth preferences I can't delete the device.

Can anyone tell me how to force the removal of the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just switch off Bluetooth? You're Mac will disconnect (obviously) and then you'll have removed your iPhone from your Bluetooth preferences.

If that doesn't work, you can do it the hard way and delete following files from ~\Library\Preferences:

- com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
- com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange.plist

**Please be advised you'll delete all your stored Bluetooth devices !!**

Comment: I've done that, when I come back my phone is still listed there marked as connected.  This is even if I've shut my phone off.  I will try deleting those files, I don't have any other bluetooth devices.

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now, it should be noted that deleting the file has no effect on this problem without a reboot. It might work after a reboot but I have too much stuff open right now to reboot. It seems that the Mountain Lion Bluetooth support is not always that stable, when connecting to my iphone it has caused my macbook to spontaneously reboot a few times already.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Bluetooth preferences,open device list,choose the item to delete then click on the "minus" icon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The OP mentioned that they couldn't delete the device. Would it be possible to revise your post to reflect something they could try?