# How to batch Delete all disconnected BlueTooth Devices on MacOS?

Tags: imac, bluetooth

I need some assistance here. I have hundreds of bluetooth devices previously connected to my MacOS which it's automatically remembered by the system. Is there a way to batch remove all of them instead of painstakingly remove them one by one ? It's really getting on my nerve because we uses the Mac to transfer photos for printing and regularly get about 4-8 new device connected to the system every day.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63562/313842 this answer claims to do so.. but comments suggest reboot also.

Comment: It is an old answer. the file is at `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` two other files are also there in ~//Library/Preferences/ .

Comment: @anki your solution does not seem to work, it seems to just forget the device names, but they appear still there with their MAC addresses instead (which makes them even more difficult to identify) ...